# Обновление данных в RedBeanPHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, pdo, redbeanphp

Ребят, как мне сделать обновление в базу данных в **RedBean**? При заходе на статью он видит её id и какие то поля из бд, но при нажатии на кнопку id становится равным 0:

```
$id = R::load('addsub', $item['id']);
echo $id;
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
R::exec("UPDATE addsub SET title='$data[title]' WHERE `id` ='$id'");
}
```

*Если поставить например id = 1, то всё работает*

Answer (score -1):

Вроде как то так :) Советую прочитать справочники redbeanphp, потому что в дальнейшем будет сложнее!

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$user = R::load('addsub',$id])
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$user->title=$data['title'];
$id = R::store($user);
```